# show output from subprocess.Popen as if run in terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, ipython

```
  subprocess.Popen('dstat --output stats.csv', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

I'm working with `ipython` and when I run the command above nothing is printed on the console. Is there a way to see the same output in the console window as I would see if I ran the command directly in a linux terminal?

Comment: `subprocess.check_call('dmesg | tail -3', shell=True, universal_newlines=True)` works fine for me. Are you doing something to the stdout before the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing up the answer below, I remembered that there was a way to break out of IPython and run like a shell. Specifically, if you start your line with an exclamation mark (`!`), IPython will execute the command as if you were on the command-line.

For example, if I run `!dstat --output stats.csv`, I get the following:

[image: Using Exclamation Mark to Break Out of IPython]

I am still keeping around the custom code-based approach below, because it was interesting to write, but obviously, the built-in solution (i.e., prefixing commands with `!`) would likely be better for your usage.

---

### Custom Solution Below This Point

How about this?

```
"""Simulate command-line execution."""
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import signal
from time import sleep


def local_command(command):
    """Simulate command execution as if on command-line."""
    env_to_pass = dict(os.environ)
    kwargs_for_popen = {
        'shell': True,
        'bufsize': 1,
        'stdin': sys.stdin.fileno(),
        'stdout': sys.stdout.fileno(),
        'stderr': sys.stderr.fileno(),
        'env': env_to_pass
    }
    # Determine which keyword we should use for putting the process I/O into
    # text-only mode.
    if sys.hexversion >= 0x3070000:
        # "text" was added as a keyword argument alias for "universal_newlines"
        # in Python 3.7, and "universal_newlines" is provided still only for
        # backwards compatibility. Let's do this right if we're going to do it.
        kwargs_for_popen['text'] = True
    else:
        # For systems with python before 3.7, use "universal_newlines"
        kwargs_for_popen['universal_newlines'] = True

    sp = subprocess.Popen(command, **kwargs_for_popen)
    while True:
        try:
            while sp.poll() is None:
                sleep(0.02)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sp.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
            sleep(0.02)
        if sp.poll() is not None:
            # Process has terminated.
            # Exit event loop.
            break
    # end while

    sp_stdout_data, sp_stderr_data = sp.communicate()
    print(sp_stdout_data)
    return sp.returncode
```

Output from IPython running Python 3.7.3 on Ubuntu:

[image: Output of Running Local Command Using Code in Answer in IPython]

The code isn't particularly pretty, but you can easily put that in its own module and then call the function. I am fairly pleased with the results inside of IPython. (Output feels fairly natural.)

Comment: Thanks Spencer D, both alternatives work great! It's a pity though that `local_command('echo "Hello, World"')` returns a `UnsupportedOperation: fileno` exception when using ipython inside Spyder or Jupyter. Do you know the cause for this error?

Comment: @HappyPy, that's odd. Is that happening on the `'stdin': sys.stdin.fileno(),` line? Either way, I will look into that a bit on my end, since I would not have expected that to be a problem. Perhaps Jupyter and Spyder alter the default STDIO handles so they can display all I/O in their interfaces. I suppose if they replaced those with generic streams, those streams may not have `fileno()` methods. According to 
[documentation for the _io.IOBase_ class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=fileno#io.IOBase), `UnsupportedOperation` should be thrown if a method is not implemented.

Comment: @HappyPy, okay, as suspected in my prior comment, it looks like Spyder replaces `sys.stdout` with an instance of the `ipykernel.iostream.OutStream` class. The pydocs for that class describe it as: `A file like object that publishes the stream to a 0MQ PUB socket. Output is handed off to an IO Thread.` Based on `inspect.getsource(ipykernel.iostream.OutStream)`, it looks like that module does not implement `fileno()`, so the `fileno()` method is resolved by the `TextIOBase` parent class, which raises. I am going to mess with this a bit to see if I can make it usable with `local_command(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the CSV output of `dstat` command to `stats.csv` file.

The output should be read from `stats.csv` file and not stdout unless you remove `--output` option passed in the command.